# Что быстрее headless chrome или headless firefox?

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пишу парсер на python, для парсинга понадобился вход, решил использоавть Selenium c Chrome и bs4.
365 объектов обрабатывает за 20 минут в обычном режиме, а в headless те же объекты обрабатываются за 35 минут...
Возможно я что-то не так делаю?
Вот как я инициализирую драйвер:

```py
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
    options.add_argument('disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    options.add_argument('no-proxy-server')
    options.add_argument('remote-debugging-port=9621')
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("disable-extensions")
    chrome_prefs = {}
    chrome_prefs['profile.default_content_settings'] = {'images': 2}
    chrome_prefs['profile.managed_default_content_settings'] = {'images': 2}
    options.experimental_options['prefs'] = chrome_prefs
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options = options)
```

UPD: Код оброботки:

```
def getPersonFromLink(self, link):
    self.browser.get(link + '/info')
    person = Person()
    profileHtml = self.browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(profileHtml, 'lxml')
    person.link = link
    person.fullName = self.textNormalizer(soup.find('li', class_ = 'inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words').text)
    person.status = self.textNormalizer(soup.find('h2', class_='mt1 t-18 t-black t-normal').text)
    person.country = self.textNormalizer(soup.find('li', class_='t-16 t-black t-normal inline-block').text)
    cis = soup.find('div', class_ = 'pv-profile-section__section-info section-info').find_all('section')
    cis.pop(0)
    for ci in cis:
        header = ci.find('header').text
        if(header == 'Phone'):
            phones = ci.find('ul').find_all('li')
            for phone in phones:
                person.phoneNumber += phone.find('span', class_ = 't-14 t-black t-normal').text + ' , '
        elif(header == 'Facebook'):
            person.facebook = self.textNormalizer(ci.find('div').find('a').text)
        elif(header == 'Twitter'):
            person.twitter = self.textNormalizer(ci.find('div').find('a').text)
        elif(header == 'VK'):
            person.vk = ci.find('div').find('span').text
    return person
```

Как его можно ускорить, или это его максимум?
Стоит ли использовать Firefox или результат будет тем же?

Comment: 1. `remote-debugging-port=9621` - попробуйте убрать вот это. 2. Думаю дело не в браузере. 3. `365 объектов обрабатывает за 20 минут в обычном режиме` показали только подключение. А код который обрабатывает эти 365 объектов где? 4. Памяти хватает или все жутко свопится?

Comment: @TotalPusher Убрал 'remote-debugging-port=96' не помогло, код обработки добавил, памяти хватает.